# CXF Duplicated URL

Tags: spring, websphere, cxf

I'm generating web services using CXF, and deploying them in Websphere Application server. In the page that list the url's of WSDL the links to these WSDL's are appearing duplicated (with the host name an its IP).

Something like this:

```
http://host/Middlewarehttp://127.0.0.1/Middleware/service?wsdl
```

When I try to access to the WSDL directly (something like `http://host/Middleware/service?wsdl`) I can view the WSDL correctly.

¿Why the link is looking like that?

Comment: please provide your ws config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved running `mvn clean` and redeploying.